# Selenium webdriver hangs on element.click

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script using Selenium's Python implementation. When the script reaches this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Top_EntryButton').click()
```

The page loads a modal dialog but the python script hangs on the command.
I debugged it a little and it seems its stuck on a while loop in *socket.py*, I guess it's waiting for some input.

Does anyone have ideas on what's wrong?

EDIT
I'm adding some more code for clarity:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.somesite.com")
driver.switch_to_frame("mainIFrame")
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Top_EntryButton').click()
```

Comment: hard to know without seeing some code

Comment: I added some more code...

Comment: Try to change `driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Top_EntryButton').click()` by `driver.execute_script("setTimeout(function () { document.querySelector(\"#ctl00_Top_EntryButton\").click() }, 1000);")`. This does the same but by injected JavaScript. Because it delay execution by 1 sec, and JS execution as asynchronous, rember to add sleep call. In my case problem was caused because the clicked button closed window and Selenium was waiting for page load after click (and some other actions). Wait for page load after window close cased infinite loop in selenium "core".

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that by the time your program gets to the .click() function, the webpage hasn't loaded yet, and thus the click function might not work properly. Try adding a time.sleep(10) line or so to your function right before the .click() line and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
capabilities['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'eager'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)

....click()
```